# How to get the Current expanded treeviewitem in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I am not able to get , only the current item which is expanded . When I am trying to get the expanded item , i am getting all the expanded items from the treeview, but I don't want that , I need to get the clicked expanded item.

Comment: By `clicked expanded item`, do you mean the currently selected item? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238304/464709.

Comment: How can you be sure of **current** expanded item? Coz you can expand more than one tree view items, correct? I guess what you want is current selected item. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In a treeview u are right ,there can be many items expanded . The problem which i am facing is i need only the Item which i expanded when I click on perticular item . Suppose in  treeview I click on a root element for example School . Under school we have a "class" as its child , then we have "student" as "Class"  item's child.So I need is "School" when I expand school , and "Class" when I expand class, and "Student" when I expand student . But here when I expand Student with treeviewitem.expand event, I am getting School and Class both because both are expanded when I expand Class .

Comment: I have tries this approach earlier , but in my case case if we do it ,the child node does not appear

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to respond to the [AfterExpand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterexpand.aspx) event.

By restricting to the click you are shutting out keyboard users.

**EDIT**

Sorry, that's WinForms. Here is the WPF solution:

```
<TreeView TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
 e.Handled=true;
```

in your `treeViewItem.Expanded` event handler. That way it will only fire for the actual item expanded and not bubble route to the parent tree view items.

Comment: We should merge our answers :)