# TreeView Sync to SelectedItem in View Model

Tags: wpf, treeview, viewmodel, selecteditem

I have a ViewModel on top of a WPF TreeView control. I want the ViewModel to be able to set and read the SelectedItem from the TreeView. However, the SelectedItem property of the TreeView is not bindable.

I am able to set and get the selected item in the code behind (using the ItemContainerGenerator and TreeViewItem.IsSelected = true) but this leads to some ugly communication between the code behind and the ViewModel.

Does anyone have a clean solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have exactly this issue.

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview

Answer (score 1):

I can provide an example.
What I do is setting the `IsSelected` property of a `TreeViewItem` (not the `TreeView` itself) in the view model, because you can bind to this.

In my view model I have a property `ElementInViewModel` which is a data structure that forms a tree itself.
I use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in my Xaml to display it.
The data object itself is of type `YourDomainType` and its child elements (of the same type) are in its `ChildElements` property.

In the view model, I set the `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` property of my data class `YourDomainType`. Because of the style defined below, they will pass this setting to the `TreeViewItem`.

Does this work for you?

```
<UserControl>

    <UserControl.Resources>        
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=ElementInViewModel}" x:Key="Cvs">
        </CollectionViewSource>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DomainModel:YourDomainType}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildElements}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>            
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>        

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </Setter>            
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>


    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cvs}}"/>
    </DockPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of proxy class to bind  SelectedItem property to In property and Out property bind to your ViewModel:

```
    public class Proxy : FrameworkElement
    {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OutProperty;

    public Proxy()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    static Proxy()
    {
        var inMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            delegate(DependencyObject p, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
                {
                    if (null != BindingOperations.GetBinding(p, OutProperty))
                    {
                        var proxy = p as Proxy;
                        if (proxy != null)
                            proxy.Out = args.NewValue;
                    }
                });

        inMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault = false;
        inMetadata.DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

        InProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("In",
                                                 typeof (object),
                                                 typeof (Proxy),
                                                 inMetadata);

        var outMetadata = new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            delegate(DependencyObject p, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
                {
                    ValueSource source = DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(p, args.Property);

                    if (source.BaseValueSource != BaseValueSource.Local)
                    {
                        var proxy = p as Proxy;
                        if (proxy != null)
                        {
                            var expected = proxy.In;
                            if (!ReferenceEquals(args.NewValue, expected))
                            {
                                Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                                    DispatcherPriority.DataBind, new Action(delegate
                                                                                {
                                                                                    proxy.Out = proxy.In;
                                                                                }));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        outMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault = true;
        outMetadata.DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

        OutProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Out",
                                                  typeof (object),
                                                  typeof (Proxy),
                                                  outMetadata);
    }

    public object In
    {
        get { return GetValue(InProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Out
    {
        get { return GetValue(OutProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OutProperty, value); }
    }
}
<Proxy In="{Binding ElementName=Tree, Path=SelectedItem}" Out="{Binding SelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TreeView x:Name="Tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"/>
```