# What's the preferred method of reacting to a selected item change using the TreeView?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, treeview, routed-events

What's the preferred method of updating other controls when a TreeViewItem has been selected?

Currently I have the following structure in my TreeView

```
DataStoreType - (DataStoreTypeViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
DataStoreType - (DataStoreTypeViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
    DataStoreEntry - (DataStoreEntryViewModel)
```

It's using the MVVM pattern, with each of the two treeview item types populated by a specific View-Model (the `DataStoreTypeViewModel` and `DataStoreEntryViewModel`).

When the user selects one of the nodes (either a `DataStoreType` or a `DataStoreEntry`) I need to be able to populate a list control with information based on the selection. So the list
control needs to be able to display two different sets of data.

I've read a little about `RoutedEvents`, but not sure if that's the way to go...

Thanks
Kieron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the approach taken [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview) then you can set a property on the view model of the selected item. Depending on the relationship between `DataStoreType` and `DataStoreEntry` you can use the same property on the view model either storing the base class or interface.

Within the property you can react by setting a collection that your list control is bound to...

VM

```
public IDataStore SelectedStore
{
    get { return _store; }
    set 
    {
        _store = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStore");
        RaisePropertyChanged("ListItems");
    }
 }

 public IEnumerbale<string> ListItems
 {
     get 
     { 
          if(_store == null)
               return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
          else 
               return _store.Items; 
     }
 }
```

XAML

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" />
```

Because of the `RaisePropertyChanged("ListItems");` in the setter for the selected item in the tree view the `ListBox` (assuming you are using something like that) will update with the new data. 
In this design I am retrieving the list of items from either the `DataStoreTypeViewModel` or `DataStoreEntryViewModel` which is better encapsulation if the data varies based on the view model type. Just have them implement an interface like `IDataStore`.

Just tweak it to suit your needs.