# XML WPF C# Binding to TreeView

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, treeview

I'm searching for hours and I'm trying to bind a XML-File to a treeView. 
In general i want to select a XML-File in a ListBox an Open the XML File in a Treeview.

The XML looks like this:

```
<test>
  <communication>
    <global>
      <server id="Server" ip="172.17.10.50" port="5072" />
    </global>
    <devices>
      <device id="Server" ip="172.18.100.50" port="3451" />
      <device id="cInterface" ip="172.17.12.52" port="3567" />
      <device id="caServer" ip="172.17.12.52" port="3000" />
    </devices>
    <groups>
      <group id="group_cInterface">
        <device id="cInterface" />
        <device id="Server" />
      </group>
    </groups>
  </communication>
</test>
```

Thanks a lot.
If my whole code is needed, feel free to ask!

**EDIT:**

Could reach this output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTLlK.png)

with this XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Communication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="693.55" Width="780">

<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
        <TextBlock x:Name="nodetext"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}"
                Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="nodetext" Property="Text"
                    Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="loadData" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="10,246,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxKonsole" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="10,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="752" SelectionChanged="listBoxKonsole_SelectionChanged" />
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" Height="214" Margin="10,282,0,0" Width="752"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />

</Grid>
</Window>
```

and this code:

```
public void listBoxKonsole_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {          

        // Get the file's location.
        string filename = listBoxKonsole.SelectedItem.ToString();

        // Make an XmlDataProvider that uses the file.
        XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
        provider.Source = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Absolute);
        provider.XPath = "./*";

        // Make the TreeView display the XmlDataProvider's data.
        treeView.DataContext = provider;



    }
```

Now my Pproblem is that i also want to show the xml Attributes and not only the XML Node Names. The attributes can be in one line with the name of the node but i dont know how to realize it.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wpf treeview bind to xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157397/wpf-treeview-bind-to-xml). The accepted answer to that question has the XML defined as a static resource in the XAML, which you may not be doing; ask for help if you have trouble adapting that answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Binding works great, but how can i make a dynamic xml binding?
When i'am selecting a XML file in the Listbox i'am getting the whole C:/..../.xml path.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "dynamic xml binding". Are you saying that you want the listbox to display only the filename?

Comment: I've found a solution on my own. The target was to build something like a XML Viewer. In a listbox i have about 20 filepathto different XML files. I wanted to select one filepath and to open that document in the treeview.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Next question is definitely coming :D

Comment: Incidentally, you can drastically simplify that hierarchical datatemplate: `<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    x:Key="NodeTemplate"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}"
    >
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>`

Answer (score 1):

I createded a TreeView for a XML Document like this.
XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AttributeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
        Margin="3,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="=&quot;" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <TextBlock Text="&quot;" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Focusable="False">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Text="Root" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="8pt" />
            <ItemsControl
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AttributeTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AttrConverter}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Path="Elements" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=FirstNode.NodeType}" Value="Text">
                <Setter TargetName="tbName" Property="Text">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} = {1}">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="FirstNode.Value"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<TreeView x:Name="LizenzAnsicht"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Elements, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NodeTemplate}"
                      />
```

The XML is used with XDocument (linq) and just setup as the DataSource for the TreeView.