# UserControl databinding with a treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, treeview

I have a `UserControl` which contains a `TreeView` and a `TextBlock`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" AllowDrop="True"  Drop="TreeView_Drop" Width="300">

                <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
          <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />

                    <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

      <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
     <TextBlock Height="23" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding= ???}" Width="187" />
```

When I select an item of the treeview, I want do show some informations contained in the item (eg : the name of the selected item).

My problem is that I don't know how doing this binding, because when I select an item, the setter IsSelected of the item class is called.

Have you a best practice for doing that ?

Comment: What is your style intended to do; it doesn't seem like it does anything to the default appearance of a tree view.

Comment: It's a treeview which looks like to .net Reflector, with an image and text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788714.aspx). And also the `BindableSelectedItemBehaviour` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview).

Comment: Interesting ! I will look at this.

Comment: It works ! I have used the MSDN documentation. Thanks for your response