# TreeItem Scroll to selected item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Does anyone has an idea of how to scroll a TreeItem to the selected item. 
I have been googling but not clear results worked for me. I tried BringIntoView() but it is not working...

Comment: Please post you code.  I know this worked from me on ListView

Comment: are you doing the item select in your code?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a behaviour for binding to selected item, see:
[Data binding to SelectedItem in a WPF Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview).
Modify the OnSelectedItemPropertyChanged to something like:

```
private static void OnSelectedItemPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ((BindableSelectedItemBehavior) sender).OnSelectedItemChanged(e.NewValue);
}

private void OnSelectedItemChanged(object newValue)
{
  var treeViewItem = AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(newValue) as TreeViewItem;
  treeViewItem.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
  treeViewItem.BringIntoView();
}
```