# Binding between Item to UI in Command(Beginner)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an `Obseravable Collection` of Items. The collection is displayed in the treeview. I want to enable removing an Item from the collection using context menu. I don't know how can I do that.

For instance, Let's say I have 4 treeviewitems (which means i have 4 Items in the `Obseravable Collection`) Now, the user wants to remove the second Item, he right clicks on the second treeviewitem, a context menu is opened and he presses on "Remove.." How can I identify which item to remove from the Collection? (I'm doing it using the `Command`)

The context menu looks like this:

```
     <ContextMenu x:Key="RemoveItemMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Remove..." Command="RemoveItem"/>
     </ContextMenu>
```

And the Command function that will be excecuted:

```
        private void RemoveItemExcecute()
    {
        //Removing the clicked Item out of the collection
    }
```

Comment: Please add more code, specifically how you use the contextmenu together with the TreeView

Comment: <TreeViewItem ContextMenu="{StaticResource RemoveItemMenu}"

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `CommandParameter` to the `MenuItem`. This way you'll be able to pass the item you wish to remove to the command.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="RemoveItemMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Remove..." Command="RemoveItem" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

You'll possibly want to modify the binding to pass the information you need. Then that information will be available to you when you handle the command:

```
private void RemoveItemExcecute(object param)
{
    // "param" is the command parameter passed to the command.
    MyItem item = (MyItem)param;
    MyItemCollection.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how can I pass the item itself?

Comment: @idish See my modified answer

Comment: Hmm, this won't work because my TreeViewItem viewmodel representation is different than the datacontext viewmodel. I need to retrieve the data context of the treeviewitem itself, is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118406/264575) which explains how to use Behaviors to add a `SelectedItem` field to your `TreeView`.

From there you could just refer to the SelectedTreeItem in your ViewModel's `RemoveItemExecute` method.

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviours:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TreeView>
```

**C#:**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyCollection { get; set; }

public MyObject MySelectedItem { get; set; } // You'll want to use INotifyPropertyChanged magic here

private void RemoveItemExcecute()
{
    MyCollection.Remove(MySelectedItem);
}
```

Another option would be to use a `CommandParameter` to pass `MySelectedItem` into the function.

**XAML:**

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="RemoveItemMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Remove..." Command="RemoveItem" CommandParameter="{Binding MySelectedItem}"/>
 </ContextMenu>
```

**C#:**

```
private void RemoveItemExcecute(object param)
{
    var selectedItem = (MyObject)param;
    MyCollection.Remove(selectedItem);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it is based on Context Menu and not on the selected item. (I'm able to do context menu not on the selected item, so it doesn't help me)