# How to Get The Selected Child Item in a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a `TreeView` with two levels, parents and children and I would like to get the value of a selected child. I used Josh Smith's [TreeView with MVVM pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) to get me started and modified the `IsSelected` method to get the item that is selected but I'm always getting the parent item.

```
static object _selectedItem = null;
......
......
public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
                {
                    _selectedItem = this;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Snippet of my XAML:

```
Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Don't know if this is causing the problem but you're changing `_selectedItem` to current item also when `value` is `false`. Would be good to add `if (value) _selectedItem = this;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SelectedItem in TreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676413/selecteditem-in-treeview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data binding to SelectedItem in a WPF Treeview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview)