# Binding with Hierarchical template Treeview

Tags: wpf, treeview

Hi I have a problem with hiearchical template.
I wrote my custom treeview items and bound using hiearchical template. But my tree view is not updating. I reffered the site http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/feac927d-b73c-4361-82f4-cd0a3f055ad0/treeview-binding-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate

My xaml

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel></vm:ViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView  Name="FT" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode}"  >
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FrthChild}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ThrdChild}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding FrthChilds}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate
         DataType="{x:Type vm:SecndChild}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ThrdChilds}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate
         DataType="{x:Type vm:FstChild}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding SecndChilds}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:ROOT}" ItemsSource="{Binding FstChilds}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My view model class

```
    namespace WpfApplication1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class ViewModel
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
            public ViewModel()
            {
                RootNode = new ROOT();
            }
            public ROOT RootNode
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
    }
```

My tree view item class

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class NodeTypes
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
        public string DisplayName
        { get; set; }
    }
    public class ROOT : NodeTypes
    {
        public ROOT()
        {
            FstChilds = new ObservableCollection<FstChild>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FstChild> FstChilds { get; set; }
    }
    public class FstChild : NodeTypes
    {
        public FstChild()
        {
            SecndChilds = new ObservableCollection<SecndChild>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<SecndChild> SecndChilds { get; set; }
    }
    public class SecndChild : NodeTypes
    {
        public SecndChild()
        {
            ThrdChilds = new ObservableCollection<ThrdChild>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<ThrdChild> ThrdChilds { get; set; }
    }
    public class ThrdChild : NodeTypes
    {
        public ThrdChild()
        {
            FrthChilds = new ObservableCollection<FrthChild>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<FrthChild> FrthChilds { get; set; }
    }
    public class FrthChild : NodeTypes
    {

    }
}
```

And I added some items in my xaml.cs...I did this for easiness for writing a test application.. I will implement this using ICommand later.

Xaml.cs

```
        namespace WpfApplication1
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
            /// </summary>
            public partial class MainWindow : Window
            {
                public MainWindow()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode = new ROOT();
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.DisplayName = "sdsds";
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RootNode"));
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds.Add(new FstChild());
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].DisplayName = "sered";
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds.Add(new SecndChild());
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsdsd";
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds.Add(new ThrdChild());
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsds";
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds.Add(new FrthChild());
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsds";
                    ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode.FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));

                }
            }
        }
```

Can any one help me in this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RootNode has to be IEnumerable so I changed your ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        RootNode = new ObservableCollection<ROOT>() { new ROOT() };
    }
    public ObservableCollection<ROOT> RootNode
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and MainWindow ctor:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode = new ROOT();
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].DisplayName = "sdsds";
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RootNode"));
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds.Add(new FstChild());
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].DisplayName = "sered";
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds.Add(new SecndChild());
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsdsd";
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds.Add(new ThrdChild());
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsds";
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds.Add(new FrthChild());
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds[0].DisplayName = "dsds";
        ((ViewModel)this.DataContext).RootNode[0].FstChilds[0].SecndChilds[0].ThrdChilds[0].FrthChilds[0].OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DisplayName"));

    }
```

and all was displayed.

**EDIT:**
Regarding your last comment you can try to use ItemContainer style

```
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding YourProperty}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: And one more thing I want to know..How can I get my selected Item? Since I have my custom treeview item is binding "IsSelected" possible? My each treeview items are of different types...

Comment: Ok...But how can I get the selected item at some point? Should I need to loop through the items and check whether IsSelected property??

Comment: yes or treeview has SelectedItem readonly property:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again...But this can be retrived as TreeView.SelectedItem...But since Iam using MVVM I dont have the UI element.And SelectedItem property is readonly...

Comment: Then you can go throught your items and find where "IsSelected"(your own property) is true or implement some behaviour mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview

Answer (score 1):

You have not raised the propertychanged events for your properties. You should do it like this:

```
           private ROOT rootNode;
            public ROOT RootNode
            {
                get
                  {
                    return _rootNode;
                  }
                set
                   {
                      _rootNode = value;
                       OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("RootNode"));
                     }
            }
```

Similarly for all the classes call PropertyChanged event from the setter of properties.

Thanks