# Move node from one branch to another in a WPF TreeView - without loosing selection

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a treeview binded to a observable collection. Each item in the collection has itself a observable collection with items.

```
public class Item
{
  public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
  public Item Parent { get; set; }
}

public Item Root { get; set; }

<TreeView ItemsSource={Binding Root.Items}>
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I want to move a node in the tree from one branch to another, but doing so makes the control loose both focus and selection.

```
UnindentItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<Item>(
  item => 
  {
     var parent = item.Parent;
     parent.Items.Remove(item);
     parent.parent.Items.Add(item);         
  }
);
```

I have tried to use the `BindableSelectedItemBehavior` from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview), but it doesn't help.

Do anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about binding to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property from your view model or code behind?:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root.Items}" TreeView.SelectedItem="{Binding Item}">
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Then in your node moving code, you can take a copy of the selected item and re-set it when you have moved the data:

```
UnindentItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<Item>(
    item => 
    {
        Item selectedItem = Item;
        var parent = item.Parent;
        parent.Items.Remove(item);
        parent.parent.Items.Add(item);
        Item = selectedItem;
    }
);
```

Comment: SelectedItem is a readonly property that can't be binded against (without a workaround as mentioned in the question). Anyway - have tried to set the selected item after the move operation, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes sorry, I keep forgetting that as I use an `Attached Property` to do that for me. Can you show us how you tried to set the selected item after the move operation?... I assume that you know that you have to set it to an item that is actually in its collection.

Comment: The code I use is the exact same code as you have. BUT the behavior I copy-pasted form the linked question has an error in it. It casts the selected item to an `TreeViewItem` when in reality it is an `Item`. That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exact same problem. This really appears to me to be a bug in WPF. After moving the node in the observable collection, the tree updates correctly and the right node is selected, but the keyboard focus gets lost. What worked for me is to just "shake" the tree a bit by getting the first treeviewitem element and setting focus on it explicitly. Then I would simply go to the element I moved and set the IsSelected property to false and then true which would bring the focus back to it. Not the most elegant of solutions, but compared to all else I've tried, pretty simple and it all looks seamless to the end user.

```
UnindentItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<Item>(
item => 
{
    Item selectedItem = Item;
    var parent = item.Parent;
    parent.Items.Remove(item);
    parent.parent.Items.Add(item);
    Item = selectedItem;

    TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem) 
(TreeName.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TreeName.Items[0]));
    tvi.Focus();
    Keyboard.Focus(tvi);
    Item.IsSelected= false;    
    Item.IsSelected = true;    
}
);


<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```