# WPF MVVM : Select TreeViewItem from ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I have a wpf apllication based on MVVM software archhitecture. It consist of treeView and ListView. When a treeView Node is clicked, all the child nodes of that node are displayed in the listview. I am able to achieve this part.

But whent the user click an item from the listView, that particular item (which is a node in treeview) should get selected in the treeView. I dont know how to do this.
Basically I want to bind property SelectedItem to listview selected item. but it seems like treeview selectedItem propeerty is readonly.

```
    <TreeView Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildAndAttributes}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,12,12,35">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tvcc:NodeViewModel}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tvcc:NodeAttributeViewModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributeName}"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AttributeValue}" Padding="2,0,0,0" Foreground="Blue" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildAndAttributes}">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some extension of tree https://stackoverflow.com/a/18265571/634219 that allows you to bind selecteditem of tree:

```
public class TreeViewEx : TreeView
{
    public TreeViewEx()
    {
        SelectedItemChanged += TreeViewEx_SelectedItemChanged;
    }

    void TreeViewEx_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }

    #region SelectedItem

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the SelectedItem possible Value of the TreeViewItem object.
    /// </summary>
    public new object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public new static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(TreeViewEx), new PropertyMetadata(SelectedItemProperty_Changed));

    static void SelectedItemProperty_Changed(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetObject = dependencyObject as TreeViewEx;
        if (targetObject != null)
        {
            var tvi = targetObject.FindItemNode(targetObject.SelectedItem);
            if (tvi != null)
                tvi.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
    #endregion SelectedItem

    public TreeViewItem FindItemNode(object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem node = null;
        foreach (object data in Items)
        {
            node = ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as TreeViewItem;
            if (node != null)
            {
                if (data == item)
                    break;
                node = FindItemNodeInChildren(node, item);
                if (node != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return node;
    }

    protected TreeViewItem FindItemNodeInChildren(TreeViewItem parent, object item)
    {
        TreeViewItem node = null;
        bool isExpanded = parent.IsExpanded;
        if (!isExpanded) //Can't find child container unless the parent node is Expanded once
        {
            parent.IsExpanded = true;
            parent.UpdateLayout();
        }
        foreach (object data in parent.Items)
        {
            node = parent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(data) as TreeViewItem;
            if (data == item && node != null)
                break;
            node = FindItemNodeInChildren(node, item);
            if (node != null)
                break;
        }
        if (node == null && parent.IsExpanded != isExpanded)
            parent.IsExpanded = isExpanded;
        if (node != null)
            parent.IsExpanded = true;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to select a `TreeViewItem` in a `TreeView` is to data bind to the [`TreeViewItem.IsSelected` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This *does* mean that you'll have to add an extra `bool IsSelected` property to your data type class, but it will then enable you to select any item from the view model. You can data bind to this property in a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

Optionally, you might also want to data bind to the [`TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isexpanded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too, so that you can select *and* expand the relevant item from the view model:

```
YourDataType item = Items.First(i => i.Id == someValue);
item.IsSelected = true;
item.IsExpanded = true;
```