# TreeView SelectedItem Behavior - Two Way Binding does not work in One Direction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, behavior

I have created a very simple example to show my problem. Maybe I just think in a wrong way.

I want to select an Item of my TreeView - and I would like to see it in the View (Blue background).

To realize the TwoWayBinding I use this Behavior: [Data binding to SelectedItem in a WPF Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview)

```
public class BindableSelectedItemBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    #region SelectedItem Property

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BindableSelectedItemBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        this.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

But if I click on an Item it does not go into the 'if' of the `OnSelectedItemChanged` because `e.newValue as TreeViewItem` is `null`

My XAML is very simple:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:BindableSelectedItemBehavior
                SelectedItem="{Binding Item}" />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Item.Text}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the sake of the convenience, here's the final solution combined of the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31988038/75500) and [ghrod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31989568/75500):

```
namespace MyPoject.Behaviors
{
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Interactivity;

  public class BindableSelectedItemBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
  {
    #region SelectedItem Property

    public object SelectedItem
    {
      get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
      set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(SelectedItem),
          typeof(object),
          typeof(BindableSelectedItemBehavior),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
            OnSelectedItemChanged));

    static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      var behavior = (BindableSelectedItemBehavior)sender;
      var generator = behavior.AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator;
      if (generator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewValue) is TreeViewItem item)
        item.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
    }
    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
      base.OnAttached();

      AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
      base.OnDetaching();

      if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, 
        RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e) =>
      SelectedItem = e.NewValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution requires C# 7.0.
Changing the code (not tested) in OnSelectedItemChanged to:
var item = generator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewValue) as TreeViewItem;
   item?.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
should fix the problem...

Comment: Does this actually work for items that aren't at the root level? Best as I can tell, each subnode has its _own_ `ItemContainerGenerator`, so you need to recurse. But on top of that, the ItemContainerGenerator doesn't immediately populate its connected, so you need to attach to its `StatusChanged` event. Recursively. Surely that can't be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedItem` property of `TreeView` does not return `TreeViewItem` in your case. It returns currently selected item from your bound `Items` collection. To get `TreeViewItem` from `SelectedItem`, you need to use `ItemContainerGenerator` here:

```
private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, 
  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var behavior = (BindableSelectedItemBehavior)sender;
    var generator = behavior.AssociatedObject.ItemContainerGenerator;
    var item = generator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewValue) as TreeViewItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        item.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the problem is, that "generator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewValue)" returns null because my Tab is not active. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @MisterPresident in my case, I'm trying to achieve this using a `TreeView`, and getting the container returns null too.

Answer (score 0):

Your OnSelectedItemChanged will only pass an object of type TreeViewItem if your actual model objects are of type TreeViewItem, which isn't going to be the case 99% of the time. You will instead have to retrieve TreeViewItem from a model object, but it will not be available if the node is currently collapsed, which makes selecting collapsed nodes very non-trivial.

I've made an effort to explain this very thoroughly in my blog, including code samples [here](http://tyrrrz.me/Blog/WPF-TreeView-SelectedItem-TwoWay-binding)