# How to get the SelectedItem of several datagrids?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, mvvm-light

Foreach treeview-item i got an own datagrid. Treeview-items and datagrids are filled by binding.

On textboxes i got a binding to the selected item of the datagrids. But the binding on these textboxes only works with the first datagrid. Every other datagrid doesn't transfer the selecteditem to the textboxes:

[image: wrong binding]

Here is the treeview with the datagrid:

```
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlaceList}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Name}">
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MachinesInPlace, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMachine, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                      SelectionMode="Single">
                            </DataGrid>
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Here is the textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PlaceList/SelectedMachine.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

I am working with MvvmLight. My ViewModel holds the PlaceList:

```
    public ObservableCollection<PlaceModel> PlaceList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PlaceModel>();

    public ObjectInspectorViewModel()
    {
        PlaceList = PlaceModel.GetPlaces(BaseResourcePaths.PlacesCsv);
    }
```

That s my place-model:

```
public class PlaceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "_CurrentObjectName";
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MachineModel> MachinesInPlace { get; set; }
    public MachineModel SelectedMachine { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<PlaceModel> GetPlaces(string filepath)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I tried something out but at last i dont know how to fix the bug. What s the problem? My suggestion is the property ''SelectedMachine'' inside the place-model...

Here is an example-project (with the additional solution of Sebastian Richter). It shows the problems: https://www.file-upload.net/download-12370581/DatagridTreeViewError.zip.html

Comment: Don't you need a SelectedItem on the treeview and then do your bindings to the textboxes based on that?  Otherwise, the bindings are just grabbing the first instance and not being updated when a treeview selection is made.

Comment: Thx for ur reply. I tried ur solution but it didnt work. I had to extend the treeview-control with the SelectedItem-property like on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3535089. I ended up with the following XAML: http://pastebin.com/VVgBtCqR Problem is that the treeview holds a list full of place and in each place is a different (datagrid)list of machines. So on treeview-select i could get which place-list is selected but i couldnt get which machine inside those place-lists is selected. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quiet sure you forget to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in you class `PlaceModel`. The problem is after you changed the selection, the Property `Placemodel.SelectedMachine` will be updated but no event will be fired to populate this change in the View.

Because you use MVVM Light you can derive from [ObservableObject](http://www.mvvmlight.net/help/SL5/html/d457231f-6af7-601d-fa1f-1fe7c9f60c57.htm)  which already implements this Interface.
So change your `PlaceModel` to following code:

```
public class PlaceModel : ObservableObject
{
    private MachineModel _selectedMachine;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "_CurrentObjectName";
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Width { get; set; }
    public string Height { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MachineModel> MachinesInPlace { get; set; }

    public MachineModel SelectedMachine
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedMachine;
        }

        set
        {
            // raises Event PropertyChanged after setting value
            Set(ref _selectedMachine, value);
        }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<PlaceModel> GetPlaces(string filepath)
    {
    [...]
}
```

**Edit:**

I guess the binding doesn't know which element to bind to from your `ObservableCollection` (many to one relation) because you set it as the reference in your `TextBox`.

So try to remove the `SelectedMachine` property from the Model and add it back to the ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
     ...
     private MachineModel _selectedMachine;
     public MachineModel SelectedMachine
     {
        get
        {
            return _selectedMachine;
        }
        set
        {
        // raises Event PropertyChanged after setting value
        Set(ref _selectedMachine, value);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Also change your XAML to following code (I used your example project):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Row #1 -->
    <Grid>
        <!-- TreeView und DataGrids-->
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlaceList}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Path=Name}">
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MachinesInPlace, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMachine, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Row #2 -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Content="ID" />
        <!-- Textboxen aktualisieren nur bei Auswahl der ersten Datagrid -->
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedMachine.Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Content="Name" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="1"
                 Text="{Binding SelectedMachine.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The key was to set the correct DataContext for `SelectedItem`. For this i used following XAML code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MachinesInPlace, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedMachine, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

With this the your example project updates the TextBoxes correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed i forgot the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-interface/`ObservableObject`. I added this idea to my code but it didnt solve the problem. In my question i added a project-example which shows the problem more exactly. I think rather that the `SelectedMachine` must be outside of the `PlaceModel`. But if i put the properties `PlaceList` and `SelectedMachine` into my viewmodel, i can not access `SelectedMachine` in my xaml-datagrid, because i set a `PlaceList` in the above treeview: http://pastebin.com/20HwpPga

Comment: I am very thankful for your effort! Problematically visual studio doesn't show me the property `DataContext.SelectedMachine` on the binding-window, so i need to set it manually. See [this picture](https://picload.org/image/rlcgogwr/binding2.png). I would never have find that out without of ur help, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I always learn something new from this questions.