# switch between viewmodels on the same view using wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to WPF MVVM, and a bit stuck. I need to switch between about 100 different tables on the same view using MVVM with wpf.
I have Treeview with the list of table names and on item selection the correct DataGrid has to be displayed beside the Treeview.
I created Model and ViewModel classes for each table. However, how do I select the right Viewmodel to bind depend on the selection.

Comment: It would help if we know what you code looks like. You could use the same ViewModel for one TreeView entry and one DataGrid e.g.

Comment: Hello Mighty, All I'm currently have my model and viewmodel classes with INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm trying to implement what Peter suggested, but still not much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem right - then you have a design problem.

**First** get the `SelectedItem` of your `TreeView`

To use the `SelectedItem`-`Binding` on a TreeView see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview). But you could do also the bad way in the code behind.

**Second** bind your `SelectedItem`

So what you want to do is:
bind the `SelectedItem` on something like a `ContentControl` or `ContentPresenter`.  Or do it the bad way in the code behind.

For example like this:

```
<Grid>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <ColumnDefinition />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}">
    <!-- Get the selected item here (watch how to in the linked answer) -->
</TreeView>


<ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                  Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"
                  >
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid>
                <!-- Your DatGrids or what ever -->
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>

</Grid>
```

**Third (optional)** If you have different `DataGrids`

You could also use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://www.wpfsharp.com/tag/datatemplateselector/) to change your Views depending on your SelectedItem too. You would use it on the `ContentPresenter` in this example.

Comment: would it make sense to combine several viewmodels into the one that is working with the view directly binding the selected model?<!-- language: c# --> <code> ObservableCollection <object> _selectedmodel; public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedModel { get { return _selectedmodel; } set { _selectedmodel = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedModel"); } } </code>

Comment: You have the right idea, but bad execution. Build your stuff with a hierarchie. So the `SelectedModel ` is a ViewModel and not a collection mate!!! Obviously the `SelectedModel` has a Field of Type ObservableCollection<WhatEver>.