# Binding From User Control to User Control - Binding Path Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am using a `UserControl` within a `UserControl`.  Everything works except one piece.  I get:

> BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''OrganizationDetailsVM' (HashCode=21529561)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem='OrganizationDetailsVM' (HashCode=21529561); target element is 'ExtendedTreeView' (Name='tvApplications'); target property is 'SelectedItem_' (type 'Object')

Here are the relevant bits:

**OrganizationDetailsVM.cs**

```
        private AdoptionApplication selectedApplication;
        public AdoptionApplication SelectedApplication
        {
            get { return this.selectedApplication; }
            set
            {
                if (this.selectedApplication != value)
                {
                    this.selectedApplication = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedApplication");
                }
            }
        }

        private object selectedTreeItem;
        public object SelectedTreeItem
        {
            get { return this.selectedTreeItem; }
            set
            {
                if (this.selectedTreeItem != value)
                {
                    this.selectedTreeItem = value;
                    SelectedApplication = selectedTreeItem as AdoptionApplication;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTreeItem");
                    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedApplication");
                }
            }
        }
        // other stuff
```

**OrganizationDetails.xaml**

```
 <uc:ApplicationsControl x:Name="ucApplications" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeItem}"
                         AddApplicationCommand="{Binding AddApplicationCommand}"
                         EditApplicationCommand="{Binding EditApplicationCommand}"
                         DeleteApplicationCommand="{Binding DeleteApplicationCommand}"/>
```

**ApplicationsControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="CareerChanges.Views.UserControls.ApplicationsControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:CareerChanges"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CareerChanges.Views.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <cc:SimpleFolderConverter x:Key="folderConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"
          Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="419*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <local:ExtendedTreeView x:Name="tvApplications"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  SelectedItem_="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding AdoptionApplications}">
            <local:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:AdoptionApplication}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource folderConverter}" ConverterParameter=", Breeds, FamilyMembers, Persons">
                            <Binding Path="Organization"/>
                            <Binding Path="ApplicationPreferences"/>
                            <Binding Path="FamilyMembers"/>
                            <Binding Path="ApplicationPersons"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Aquamarine">
                        <TextBlock Text="Application (" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ApplicationID}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=") "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ApplicationDate, StringFormat=dd-MMM-yyyy}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationStatusID, Converter={StaticResource ApplicationStatusConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:ApplicationPreference}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Colours}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BreedID, Converter={StaticResource BreedConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Colours.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:FolderItem}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count}" Foreground="Blue" />
                        <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:Person}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Given}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Surname}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:FamilyMemberType}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FamilyMemberTypeID, Converter={StaticResource FamilyTypeConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:ColourPreference}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ColourID, Converter={StaticResource ColourConverter}}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text=" Male: "/>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Male}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" Female: "/>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Female}" IsEnabled="False"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type cc:Organization}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Organization: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OrganizationName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:ExtendedTreeView.Resources>
        </local:ExtendedTreeView>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
            <Button Name="btnAddApplication" Margin="2" Command="{Binding Path=AddApplicationCommand}">Add</Button>
            <Button Name="btnEditApplication" Margin="2" Command="{Binding Path=EditApplicationCommand}">Edit</Button>
            <Button Name="btnDeleteApplication" Margin="2" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteApplicationCommand}">Delete</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

***ApplicationsControl.xaml.cs***

```
        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register(
               "SelectedItem",
               typeof(object),
               typeof(ApplicationsControl),
               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                   null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Finally, this is the code for the `ExtendedTreeView` from this question: [Data binding to SelectedItem in a WPF Treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview)

***ExtendedTreeView.cs***

```
    public class ExtendedTreeView : TreeView
    {
        public ExtendedTreeView()
            : base()
        {
            this.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(___ICH);
        }

        void ___ICH(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            if (SelectedItem != null)
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItem_Property, SelectedItem);
            }
        }

        public object SelectedItem_
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItem_Property); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItem_Property, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItem_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem_", typeof(object), typeof(ExtendedTreeView), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

For some reason, the binding isn't making it from `OrganizationDetailsVM`, through `OrganizationDetails.xaml` to `ApplicationsControl.xaml` and down to `ExtendedTreeview`.  All the other bindings work perfectly. The tree view does what it should, except for binding to the selected item.

To sum up, I'm having a problem getting from here:

```
 <uc:ApplicationsControl x:Name="ucApplications" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeItem}"
                         AddApplicationCommand="{Binding AddApplicationCommand}"
                         EditApplicationCommand="{Binding EditApplicationCommand}"
                         DeleteApplicationCommand="{Binding DeleteApplicationCommand}"/>
```

... to here:

```
<local:ExtendedTreeView x:Name="tvApplications"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        SelectedItem_="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AdoptionApplications}">
```

It boils down to this binding not working:

```
SelectedItem_="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!  I'm still new at data binding.  After looking at some other code, I modified the binding to:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:DogPersonsControl}}}">
```