# I can not Bind a Path using event triggers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, eventtrigger

I have just started to learn Xaml, and currently building a app to control data from SQL vith MVVM architecture. I have been working on to open a new page by using a DataGrid.SelectionChanged event for 2 days. However, when I try to write xaml as below I get the error :

'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AddSourceUpdatedHandler' property of type 'BeginStoryboard'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

You can see I can open the CustomerView from OperationsView by using the command of RadioButton, perfectly.

I would appreciate for your any help.

My xaml is below:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tourism.MainPage.MVVM.View.OperationsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tourism.MainPage.MVVM.View"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Tourism.MainPage.MVVM.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="800"
             d:DesignWidth="2000"
             Background="#24292f">



    <StackPanel>


        <DataGrid x:Name="dgwOperationMain"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="50,50,0,0"
                  Width="700"
                  Height="425"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  Loaded="dgwOperationMain_Loaded"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  FontFamily="/Fonts/#Poppins"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                  SelectionChanged="dgwOperationMain_SelectionChanged">

            <DataGrid.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.SelectionChanged">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Binding.SourceUpdated="{Binding Path=           CustomerViewCommand}">

                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </DataGrid.Triggers>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DocumentCode"
                                    MinWidth="120"
                                    Binding="{Binding DocumentCode}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Operator"
                                    MinWidth="50"
                                    Binding="{Binding Operator}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="StartDate"
                                    MinWidth="70"
                                    Binding="{Binding StartDate}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EndDate"
                                    MinWidth="70"
                                    Binding="{Binding EndDate}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pax"
                                    MinWidth="20"
                                    Binding="{Binding Pax}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Room"
                                    MinWidth="20"
                                    Binding="{Binding Room}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Currency"
                                    MinWidth="30"
                                    Binding="{Binding Currency}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgwCustomerOperation"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="790,-425,0,0"
                  Width="752"
                  Height="425"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  FontFamily="/Fonts/#Poppins" />

        <RadioButton Content="Customers"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                     x:Name="btnCustomer"
                     Foreground="White"
                     Background="YellowGreen"
                     FontFamily="/Fonts/#Poppins"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Height="50"
                     Width="180"
                     Margin="500,0,0,0"
                     Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                     Command="{Binding Path= CustomerViewCommand}"
                     Checked="btnCustomer_Checked" />

        <ContentControl Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
    </StackPanel>


</UserControl>
```

This part of the code is giving me the error:

```
<BeginStoryboard Binding.SourceUpdated="{Binding Path= CustomerViewCommand}">
```

My ObservableObject:

```
 public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Relay Command;

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Predicate<object> _canExecute;              

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
                
        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, /* Func<object,bool>*/Predicate<object> canExecute /*= null*/ )
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }
        
        public bool CanExecute( object parameter ) 
        {
             return /*_canExecute == null || */_canExecute(parameter);  
        } 

        public void Execute( object parameter )     
        { 
         _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel;

```
 public abstract class ViewModel :ObservableObject{}
```

MainViewModel;

```
 public class MainViewModel : Core.ViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand OpeartionViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand CustomerViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand SettingsViewCommand { get; set; }   


        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private INavigationService _navigation;
        public INavigationService Navigation
        {
            get => _navigation;
            set
            {
                _navigation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel(INavigationService navService) 
        {
            Navigation = navService;
            Navigation.NavigateTo<HomeViewModel>();
            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<HomeViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o => true);
            OpeartionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<OperationViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o => true);
            CustomerViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<CustomerViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o => true);    
            SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<SettingsViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o => true);
          
        }
    }
```

OperationViewModel;

```
public class OperationViewModel : Core.ViewModel
    {

        private INavigationService _navigation;
        public INavigationService Navigation
        {
            get => _navigation;
            set
            {
                _navigation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public RelayCommand CustomerViewCommand { get; set; }   
        public OperationViewModel(INavigationService navigation)
        {       
            Navigation = navigation;
            CustomerViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<CustomerViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o => true);


        }
    }
```

CustomerViewModel;

```
 public class CustomerViewModel : Core.ViewModel
    {
        private INavigationService _navigation;
        public INavigationService Navigation
        {
            get => _navigation;
            set
            {
                _navigation = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public RelayCommand OpeartionViewCommand { get; set; }               
        public CustomerViewModel(INavigationService navigation)
        {
            Navigation = navigation;
            OpeartionViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { Navigation.NavigateTo<OperationViewModel>(); }, canExecute: o/*: object*/ => true);
        }
 

    }
```

Navigation Service;

```
 public interface INavigationService
    {
        ViewModel CurrentView { get; }
        void NavigateTo<T>() where T : ViewModel;
    }
    public class NavigationService : ObservableObject, INavigationService
    {
        private readonly Func<Type, ViewModel> _viewModelFactory;

        public  ViewModel _currentView;
        public ViewModel CurrentView
        {
            get => _currentView;
            private set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public NavigationService(Func<Type,ViewModel> viewModelFactory)     
        {
            _viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;
        }

        public void NavigateTo<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModel
        {
            ViewModel viewModel =_viewModelFactory.Invoke(typeof(TViewModel));
            CurrentView = viewModel; 
        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs;

```
  public partial class App : Application
    {
        private readonly ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public App()
        {
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();  //specifying the DI Container
            services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>(provider => new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = provider.GetRequiredService<MainViewModel>()
            });
            services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
            services.AddSingleton<OperationViewModel>();
            services.AddSingleton<HomeViewModel>();
            services.AddSingleton<CustomerViewModel>();     
            services.AddSingleton<SettingsViewModel>();             
            services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, Services.NavigationService>(); 

            services.AddSingleton<Func<Type, ViewModel>>(serviceProvider => viewModelType => (ViewModel)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(viewModelType));

            _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();     

        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var mainWindow = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
            mainWindow.Show();
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

    }
```

App.xaml;

```
<Application x:Class="Tourism.MainPage.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tourism.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Tourism.MainPage.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Tourism.MainPage.MVVM.View"
             
    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>     
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/TextBoxTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
                <view:HomeView />
            </DataTemplate>
            
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:OperationViewModel}"> 
                <view:OperationsView />
            </DataTemplate>
        
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:CustomerViewModel}">      
                <view:CustomerView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsView />       
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: As the error message correctly tells you, SourceUpdated is an event. You can not bind it to an ICommand (you can not bind it at all). Perhaps use something like EventToCommand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4898946/1136211. Besides that, it is unclear what Binding.SourceUpdated on a BeginStoryboad is supposed to do in the first place.