# wpf CommunityToolkit how get treeview(Model) selecteitem?

Tags: wpf

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
         {
             [ObservableProperty]
             private List<LzMenu> books=new List<LzMenu>();
             public MainViewModel()
             {
                books.Add(new LzMenu() { MenuIcon = "\ue96d", MenuName = "History" });
                books.Add(new LzMenu() { MenuIcon = "\ue95e", MenuName = "Novel" });
                books.Add(new LzMenu() { MenuIcon = "\ue95e", MenuName = "Science" });
             }
            [RelayCommand]
            private void CategorySelectedItem(string m)
            {
               Debug.WriteLine(m);
            }
        }
```

```xml
 <TreeView x:Name="treeView1"
                      Grid.Row="1" pu:TreeViewHelper.ItemsHeight="60" 
                      Style="{StaticResource MainMenuTreeViewStyle}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
                <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="60">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuIcon}"
                                 FontFamily="{StaticResource 
       PanuonIconFont}"
                                 FontSize="16" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MenuName}" 
       x:Name="textbm" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction
                            Command="{Binding 
        CategorySelectedItemCommand}" CommandParameter=" 
          {Binding MenuName}"/>       
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TreeView>
```

When wpf TreeView is selected, how do I get selected node (or the currently bound book category entity)?,CategorySelectedItemCommand not working.i studying  CommunityToolkit  ,i can't use CommunityToolkit bingd and get select Node.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000040/data-binding-to-selecteditem-in-a-wpf-treeview)?